# How to get if there is any data avaliable on socket to read in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

Is there any bool - `has data`/`has not` or alternative? no actual read is needed - only information if there is data avaliable to read on sockety or not, as a sync method. So  Is there is any such data avaliable on socket to read method in `boost::asio::tcp::ip::socket`?

Answer (score 5):

There is the [`bytes_readable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/bytes_readable.html) functionality. Using it you can check if there is data available to read without blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Another, possibly simpler, method is the [boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::available()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/available.html) non-blocking function:

```
asio::ip::tcp::socket *s;
. . .
size_t availBytes = s->available();
if (availBytes > 0)
{
. . .
}
```